# How to add class to a specific siblings of element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, siblings

I want to find if an element has class `lesson_read` then add a class `found` to `.course_section` that comes just above it. but don't add class to `.course_section` which comes below it. here is the html

```
<table class="table">               
    <tbody>
        <tr class="course_section "><!-- this should have class "found" -->
            <td colspan="4">Introduction to AEM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_lesson lesson_read">
            <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-play"></i></td>
            <td><a href="#">Introduction to AEM</a></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_lesson lesson_read">
            <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-play"></i></td>
            <td><a href="#">Installing AEM</a></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_lesson">
            <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-task"></i></td>
            <td>AEM Installation Quiz</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Unlimited</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_section">
            <td colspan="4">AEM Environment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_lesson">
            <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-text-document"></i></td>
            <td>AEM Instances</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_lesson">
            <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-play"></i></td>
            <td>Developer Tools</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried this

```
jQuery('.course_section').each(function() {
    var c='';
    jQuery(this).siblings().each(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('lesson_read')){
            c='found';      
        }      
    });
    if(c=='found'){
        jQuery(this).addClass(c);   
    }
});
```

However this adds class `found` to every course section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) that select preceding sibling of element.

```
$(".lesson_read").prev(".course_section").addClass("found");
```

```js
$(".lesson_read").prev(".course_section").addClass("found");
```

```css
.found {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">               
  <tbody>
    <tr class="course_section"><!-- this should have class "found" -->
      <td colspan="4">Introduction to AEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="course_lesson lesson_read">
      <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-play"></i></td>
      <td><a href="#">Introduction to AEM</a></td>
      <td> </td>
      <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="course_lesson lesson_read">
      <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-play"></i></td>
      <td><a href="#">Installing AEM</a></td>
      <td> </td>
      <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="course_lesson">
      <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-task"></i></td>
      <td>AEM Installation Quiz</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Unlimited</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="course_section">
      <td colspan="4">AEM Environment</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="course_lesson">
      <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-text-document"></i></td>
      <td>AEM Instances</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="course_lesson">
      <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-play"></i></td>
      <td>Developer Tools</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: prev() only works for selecting preceding sibling. Here it's working because of siblings of the first tr with course_section class has lesson_read class.

Comment: @MithuCN *add a class `found` to `.course_section` that comes just above it*

Comment: Please try your code again after removing the first lesson_read class from tr.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) to get all previous siblings which have class **course_section** then have to use [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) to get last previous siblings(course_section) of lesson_read class

```js
$('.lesson_read').prevAll('.course_section').last().addClass('found');
```

```css
.found{
color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">               
    <tbody>
        <tr class="course_section "><!-- this should have class "found" -->
            <td colspan="4">Introduction to AEM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_lesson">
            <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-play"></i></td>
            <td><a href="#">Introduction to AEM</a></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_lesson lesson_read">
            <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-play"></i></td>
            <td><a href="#">Installing AEM</a></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_lesson">
            <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-task"></i></td>
            <td>AEM Installation Quiz</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Unlimited</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_section">
            <td colspan="4">AEM Environment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_lesson">
            <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-text-document"></i></td>
            <td>AEM Instances</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="course_lesson">
            <td class="curriculum-icon"><i class="icon-play"></i></td>
            <td>Developer Tools</td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 00:00:00</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```